Why does the ionisation energy of an electron depend only on n and l, when the electron Z(eff) is dependent on the four quantum numbers?
I am a bit confused by the classnotes of MIT.
It says that the binding energy of an electron (in a multi electronic atom) depends on $n$ and on $l$. Especially it says:
$$ E_{n,l} = -E_{I;n,l} = -\frac{R_H {Z_\mathrm{eff}^{n,l}} ^2}{n^2},$$
where $E_{n,l}$ stands for binding energy and $E_{I;n,l}$ stands for ionization energy.
What confuses me is that, at fixed $n$ and $l$, the $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ changes as the third and fourth quantum numbers change. For instance, $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ of lithium is different from $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ of beryllium.
I know I'm wrong (since most textbooks represent the $2s^1$ electron at the same energy level as the second electron in $2s^2$).
Can anyone help me to spot where my understanding fails ?
Can anyone indicate which one of the $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ (among lithium's and beryllium's) we must choose in order to have the binding energy of the $2s$ orbital ?

Lithium and beryllium have different Zeff because of different nucleus, not spin number!

Numerical values of $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ for $\mathrm{2s}$ @Mithoron's comment are $1.279$ for $\ce{Li}$ and $1.912$ for $\ce{Be}$, according to Wikipedia. See this and this for emperical calculations.

The premise of the question title is wrong. Ionization energy and effective charge of a nucleus depend on multiple things, not just quantum numbers.

The $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ is not a constant. It varies with nuclear charge. Every element has different nuclear charge. Your examples, lithium and beryllium, are different elements.
The four quantum numbers: n, l, m, s, are said to have the same value even in different elements (when considering ions of different elements with the same number of electrons) because all nuclei are approximately point-like. The two quantum numbers: m and s, are left out of the equation, because their effects on binding energy are negligible.
To conclude: $2s$ orbital binding energies are different depending on element. There is no "The" binding energy of $2s$ orbital. $2s$ just indicates the n=2 and l=0 quantum numbers in whatever atom or ion you have.

The $Z(eff)$ is only dependent on n and l quantum number. Because these two quantum numbers only dependent on distance.
We know that:
Z(eff) $\propto$ 1 / atomic size (or) distance from the nucleus
As the magnetic quantum number (m) and spin quantum number (s) are indipendent of the Atomic radius (or) distance from the nucleus.
The magnetic quantum number represents the orientation of the orbital along the same orbit and spin quantum number represents the spin of the electron in the same orbitals.
The energy levels of $2s^1$ and $2s^2$ will depends upon the elements by which these configuration accumulated.
For instance,
The  Li has a configuration [He]$2s^1$ will have energy as 6.044 ev/atom
Then, Be has a configuration [He]$2s^2$ will have energy as 3.4 ev/atom
So, by the example above we can conclude that The energy levels of $2s^1$
and $2s^2$
will depends upon the elements by which these configuration accumulated.
